# SHA-3 variable length hash same as truncating normal hash in Java using BouncyCastle

Tags: java, hash, bouncycastle, sha-3

I need to generate a fixed length hash of 30 characters based on some input data (like a customer email address) in Java. After some searching, I found out about SHA-3 sponge functions, where I can specify the required length. I implemented the following using Bouncy Castle `SHAKEDigest` class.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String message = "Hello World!";
        System.out.println(getHash(message, 64));
        System.out.println(getHash(message, 30));
        System.out.println(getHash(message, 20));
    }

    static String getHash(final String message, final int lengthInCharacters) {
        final byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        final SHAKEDigest digest = new SHAKEDigest(128);

        final byte[] hashBytes = new byte[lengthInCharacters / 2];
        digest.update(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.length);
        digest.doOutput(hashBytes, 0, hashBytes.length);

        return Hex.toHexString(hashBytes);
    }
}
```

If I execute it, I get the following output:

```
aacfe6ebd3737d9f195c837c5281d3f87646ecd7e43864e1a40456e40f264046
aacfe6ebd3737d9f195c837c5281d3
aacfe6ebd3737d9f195c
```

I expected that the hashes are totally different depending on the requested length. As it looks now, I could also generate a simple SHA-256 hash using JDK `MessageDigest` and just truncate it on the required length.

Am I doing something wrong or am I misunderstanding the point of those sponge functions?

Full code with unit tests is available at: https://github.com/steinsag/java-dynamic-hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nit: SHAKEn are actually Extensible Output Functions (XOFs) *built on* the Keccak sponge in the same way that the (fixed length) SHA3 hashes are; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3#Instances .

But the point you seem to have misunderstood is that the underlying sponge makes each/all of these deterministic -- a given instance (parameterization) produces the same output everytime for the same input, and is not affected by the output size as such. Thus SHA3-256(m) is not the first 256 bits of SHA3-512(m) because it has different parameters, while SHAKE128(m,256) *is* the first 256 bits of SHAKE128(m,512) but is *not* SHAKE256(m,256).

Yes, you can truncate any SHA3 hash (or SHA2 hash for that matter) to a size smaller than its normal size and get a smaller but otherwise equally good crypto hash (pseudo-random, irreversible and noncolliding for real data), and people have in fact been doing exactly this for decades. But you can't safely *increase* it, which you can with an XOF like SHAKE.